# SyntaxError: Unexpected token } (www.codecademy.com)

Tags: javascript

I am currently having a problem of which whenever I try to submit my code to CodeCademy, I get an error. `SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`

Here is the code:

```
 // Check if the user is ready to play!
confirm("Are you ready to play")
var age = prompt("What is your age?")

if (age === 13) {
    console.log("You are old enough to play");
} else {
    console.log("Play On!")
}

var JustinBieberSux = "You are at a Justin Bieber concert, and you hear this lyric 'Lace my shoes off, start racing.'"

console.log(JustinBieberSux);

console.log("Suddenly, Bieber stops and says, 'Who wants to race me?'")

var userAnswer = "Do you want to race Bieber on stage?"

prompt(userAnswer);

if (userAnswer === "yes") {
    console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!")
} else {
    console.log("Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'")
}

var feedback = prompt("Rate the Game out of 10?")

if (feedback < 8) {
    console.log("Thank you! We should race again at the next concert!")
} else {
    console.log("I'll keep practicing coding and racing."
    }
```

Any help would be well appreciated.
Thanks,
Sir_smiggles

Comment: Your last `console.log()` is missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: also, make sure you end every statement with a semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final `console.log()` call is missing a final bracket.

Your code should look something like this.

```
 // Check if the user is ready to play!
confirm("Are you ready to play");
var age = prompt("What is your age?");

if (age === 13) {
    console.log("You are old enough to play");
} else {
    console.log("Play On!");
}

var JustinBieberSux = "You are at a Justin Bieber concert, and you hear this lyric 'Lace my shoes off, start racing.'";

console.log(JustinBieberSux);

console.log("Suddenly, Bieber stops and says, 'Who wants to race me?'");

var userAnswer = "Do you want to race Bieber on stage?";

prompt(userAnswer);

if (userAnswer === "yes") {
    console.log("You and Bieber start racing. It's neck and neck! You win by a shoelace!");
} else {
    console.log("Oh no! Bieber shakes his head and sings 'I set a pace, so I can race without pacing.'");    }

var feedback = prompt("Rate the Game out of 10?");

if (feedback < 8) {
    console.log("Thank you! We should race again at the next concert!");
} else {
    console.log("I'll keep practicing coding and racing.");
}
```

I also added semi-colons where appropriate. Get used to using these at the end of each lines, or else you'll run into syntax errors in less compatible browsers.

Comment: Happy to help! Please accept answer if you feel it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the code you missed one )

```
else {
    console.log("I'll keep practicing coding and racing.")
    }
```